# flutter google_mlkit_digital_ink_recognition candidates scores always 0

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-mlkit, handwriting-recognition

I am using `google_mlkit_digital_ink_recognition` in flutter to recognize the letter that user draws.
it is working fine and the candidates are shown, but the problem is `candidate.score` is always `0`.

code example:

```
 var _digitalInkRecognizer = DigitalInkRecognizer(languageCode: 'ar');

 final candidates = await _digitalInkRecognizer.recognize(_ink);
 candidates.forEach((element) {
        print(element.text+element.score.toString());
      });
```

Comment: Q: Integer "0" ... or null?  Per the [documention](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/digitalink/RecognitionCandidate#public-float-getscore):  "This value is populated only for models that support scores. Otherwise a null value is returned."

Comment: @paulsm4 it is 0, the problem is there is score from logs that comes from native, and it logs best score also, but the code `candidate.score` in dart is always 0